# How to add Multiple column value?

Tags: sql, oracle

[Picture is of table in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8EMu.png)

I have to query drivers who have covered more than 430,000 miles between January 2010 to December 2012.
For which i am trying

```
SELECT t.DRIVERID 
FROM BBI_BC.TRUCKS t
WHERE t.JAN_2010_MILES + t. FEB_2010_MILES + .....+ t.DEC_2012_MILES > 43000;
```

Comment: Don't use a picture, add table definitions and descriptions instead. More importantly, what is your problem? You want to find the drivers and you have a query, do you think it returns the wrong data or what?

Comment: That would work so what is your question? If it is how to avoid typing pit all those columns the answer is you can't. The designer of that table opted to ignore the well-established industry standard rules of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Why they did that is irrelevant: the upshot is that everybody who queries the table has to write tedious and hard-to-maintain queries.

Comment: @APC ain't that a tedious approach, i was looking for more of generic approach to find the results

Comment: What kind of database model are you using? Does your table grow each month with new columns? I suggest you to review with the architect that model, is quite a bit weird

Comment: @JaimeDrq Relational model

Comment: Do you use Oracle or MySQL? Please set only relevant tags.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Oracle

Comment: Probably you could create a view containing an `unpivot` clause so that it presented the data in a normalised format with a date column (or maybe separate `YEAR` and `MONTH` columns). Then you could just sum the mileage column for whatever period you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

So the question is, how to avoid typing all those columns in the WHERE clause. The answer is you can't. The designer of that table opted to ignore the well-established industry standard rules of database normalization. [Find out more.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) Why they did that is irrelevant: the upshot is that everybody who queries the table has to write tedious and hard-to-maintain queries.

There is the option of dynamic query generation: run this query, then cut'n'paste the output into your WHERE clause:

```
select ' + t.' || column_name
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'BBI_BC'
and table_name = 'TRUCKS'
and (column_name like '%2010_MILES'
     or column_name like '%2011_MILES'
     or column_name like '%2012_MILES')
order by column_id;
```

---

I suspect this is a homework question. It is important that you realise that the true lesson is: *data modelling is very important and denormalisation is Teh Suck!*

Even the way the table's columns have been named is poor: it would be better if they were named MILES_2010_01, MILES_2010_02 etc, because at least then you could have written the dynamic query as

```
where column_name between 'MILES_2010_01' and 'MILES_2012_12'
```

---

With a properly modelled table - that is, with records for each month and just two columns for MONTHLY_MILES and MONTHLY_GAS - the query would look like this:

```
SELECT t.DRIVERID 
FROM BBI_BC.TRUCKS t
WHERE t.year between 2010 and 2012
group by t.driverid having sum(t.monthly_miles) >43000
```

Comment: How to get particular query result which i asked?

Comment: You have to write it out long hand. All you can is save yourself some typing by querying the data dictionary to generate a bit of the code.

Answer (score 2):

If the values can contain `NULL` values then you will need to use `COALESCE` or `NVL`:

```
SELECT DRIVERID 
FROM   BBI_BC.TRUCKS
WHERE  COALESCE( JAN_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( FEB_2010_MILES, 0)
     + .....
     + COALESCE( DEC_2012_MILES, 0) > 430000;
```

If you want to automatically generate the query then:

```
SELECT 'SELECT DRIVERID 
FROM   BBI_BC.TRUCKS
WHERE  ' || LISTAGG( 'COALESCE( ' || TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2010-01-01', LEVEL - 1 ), 'MON_YYYY' ) || '_MILES, 0)', '
     + ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL ) || ' > 430000;' AS sql
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2010-01-01', LEVEL - 1 ) <= DATE '2012-12-01';
```

Which outputs:

```
SELECT DRIVERID 
FROM   BBI_BC.TRUCKS
WHERE  COALESCE( JAN_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( FEB_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( MAR_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( APR_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( MAY_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JUN_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JUL_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( AUG_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( SEP_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( OCT_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( NOV_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( DEC_2010_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JAN_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( FEB_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( MAR_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( APR_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( MAY_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JUN_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JUL_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( AUG_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( SEP_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( OCT_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( NOV_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( DEC_2011_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JAN_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( FEB_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( MAR_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( APR_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( MAY_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JUN_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( JUL_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( AUG_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( SEP_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( OCT_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( NOV_2012_MILES, 0)
     + COALESCE( DEC_2012_MILES, 0) > 430000;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar solution to APC's , but returns the result dynamically. ( works for 12c +)

```
DECLARE
    miles_cond   VARCHAR2(20) := ' > 43000';
    v_where      VARCHAR2(1000);
    x            SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ' WHERE '
        ||
            LISTAGG(column_name,' + ') WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    column_name
            )
        || miles_cond
    INTO v_where
    FROM
        all_tab_columns
    WHERE
        owner = 'BBI_BC'
        AND table_name = 'TRUCKS'
        AND REGEXP_LIKE ( column_name,
                          '201[0-2]_MILES' )
    ORDER BY
        column_id;

    OPEN x FOR 'SELECT * FROM TRUCKS' || v_where;

    dbms_sql.return_result(x);
END;
/
```

And of course, you could add a similar logic like MT0's to handle nulls.

Comment: I deliberately avoided the dynamic SQL route because it's not a query. If I am correct that this is a homework question I think the teacher would be surprised to see something like this submitted by a student.

Comment: @APC : Well, the answer is posted already and I can't do much now:-). I hope someday in future his boss will assign him a task - more complicated SQL for which I wouldn't come here to answer.